# Entity Framework With mysql Database First

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

i'm working in a new project with c# and we want to use entity framework 6 but everytime we want to generate the models based on the database we have in usage. But when i'm generating a ADO.Net model using the wizard, after i select the database and the entity framework i click on the "next" button and instead appear the window to select the tables , the windows disappear without any type of error.

I'm using visual studio 2017 community edition and i've installed the mysql connector v.8.0.11. If i downgrade the mysql connector version and entity framework to v5 everything works without any problem, but after i update the connector and entity framework to version 6.* i get the problem i've reported above.

Comment: Hi, have you found any solution ?

Answer (score 11):

So after struggling for 3 days myself I FINALLY found the problem...

So the MySql.Data and MySql.Data.Entity that you have to download from NuGet packages versions are directly correlated with the version of the MySql Connector/NET that have to download.

And when you go look the latest version of MySql.Data.Entity is 6.10.7, so this means when download Connector/NET 8 then there is a version incompatibility which results in the ADO.Net data entity wizard closing.

Download the following and BAM it works:

```
MySql for visual studio 
MySql Connector/NET v6.10.7
```

NuGet packages:

```
Entityframework v6.1.3    
MySql.Data v6.10.7    
MySql.Data.Entity v6.10.7
```

Comment: I had to do this way as well. I think it has to do with the db version in my case.

Comment: that worked for me and you can download the connector from here https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-net/

Comment: That was really helpful, I went for 6.10.8 version for connector & both packages. It worked!.. The thing is versions must be exactly same!

Comment: Possibly useful resource: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-versions.html

Answer (score 4):

One thing worth to note:

You will need different Mysql EntityFramework Package for the Mysql version 6 and version 8. (This maybe why the poster has downgraded his/her mysql connector from 8 to 6)

If your mysql connector is version 8.x.x, You may need to install this NuGet Package:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.EntityFramework/

If you mysql connector is version 6.x.x you will need:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.Entity/

And install exactly the same version as your mysql connector. Otherwise, something will not work.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this problem with following config at Web.config

```
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework, Version=8.0.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
  <providers>
    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework, Version=8.0.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
  </providers>
</entityFramework>
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
    <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=8.0.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D" />
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Also I referenced to:

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.EntityFramework (8.0.11)
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/ (8.0.11)

Answer (score 1):

This is a issue with the version of the MySQL connector packages you are using.  In my case, I am using `MySQL.Data, MySQL.Entity and MySQL.Web` from Nuget.  If I use any version after 6.9.11 then I get the behavior you mention.

Comment: Your question is probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49036983/visual-studio-2017-not-showing-mysql-in-connection-list

Comment: When i do that everything works fine, but i lost access to Entity framework v6 and its a requirement for this project. In your case you are using v5 or v6 of entity framework?

Comment: Nuget tells me: 6.2.0

Comment: If you dont mind can you try generate a model from database using that version ?

Comment: No problem.  My test worked.  In the linked answer above there is a bit about removing the default version of "MySQL for Visual Studio" and installing the the latest development version (2.0.5).  Basically, I don't think Oracle actually tests the MySQL software it produces.

Comment: tried following the steps of the link and got the same problem. But i will try test this steps on other pc, just to check if is something wrong with my setup.

Comment: Also, don't forget about rebooting your PC after the uninstalls/reinstalls.  I seem to recall being extremely frustrated in this process and rebooted after each operation.

Answer (score 0):

-First Step- 
using mySql installer : https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/

Download 
1 - mySql router 
2 - Connector/ODBC 
3 - Connector/C++ 
4 - Connector/Net 
5 - MySQl Server  
All , exactly in version : 8.0.12 
 
Then go to `visual studio > manage nugget packages > browse(tab)` (and install) 
1 - entityFramework -> version 6 
2 - mysql.data -> version 8.0.12 
3 - mysql.data.entity -> version 6 
4 - mysql.data.entityFramework -> version 8.0.12

Then go to `visual studio > manage nugget packages > updates(tab)` 
update Google.protoBuf to version `3.6.0`

-Second Step- 
`Right click your project > Add new Item > Data (left navbar) > Ado.net Data Model` 
The Connection dialogue will appear, create a new connection using your Mysql (version 8.0.12) credentials. 
(check the input : include the sensitive data in the connectionString ..)

You will get an error ! that because the preconfigured MySqlProviderServices comes with the version 8.0.11 , all you have to do is to change it in the file App.config (next step).
the problem is : when you go look the latest version of MySql.Data.Entity is 6.10.7, so this means when download Connector/NET 8 then there is a version incompatibility which results in the ADO.Net data entity wizard closing.

 
-Third step (final)- 
go to your App.config file , and change your "providers" Tag to become like that

```
<providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <!--<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.10.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />-->
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework, Version=8.0.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
</providers>
```

Thats's All , now build the project and you're done you can create your Entity Data Model
(database first for example..) and map your MySql database and query it on your project

ressources : 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xvgeeaVP4M4 
https://www.devjockeys.com/blog/c-sharp/using-entity-framework-with-mysql-a-code-first-example/ 
https://ozanecare.com/connect-mysql-with-visual-studio-2019/ 
[Entity Framework With mysql Database First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50234960/entity-framework-with-mysql-database-first)

Comment: What version of VS are you using? I'm able to see the Data Model wizard but it seems to crash and reopen the "Add Item" dialogue

Comment: @Daniel this is exactly the problem that I had mentioned, it happens when you have at least one different version of the components , that's why I suggested on having the same versions, verify your app.config file, or try re-installing the correct version of each component .  ps : I have `Visual Studio 2019` (this works also for visual studio 2017 and 2015 #tested )